# Spark SQL with When condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning Spark Sql and tried below code for my study. Actually I am doing similar query in Spark Sql

```
select open , case when open < 160 then "Bad" else "Good" end as status from table_name;
```

In spark sql using data frame i am tried below code

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("citiGroupData").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

      val baseData = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv(filePath)
      // baseData.foreach(s => println(s.getAs("Low")))

      import sparkSession.implicits._
      baseData.printSchema()


      baseData.select("Open").show()
```

My Schema details

```
root
 |-- MyDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Open: double (nullable = true)
 |-- High: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Low: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Close: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Volume: integer (nullable = true)
```

The below line is causing compile time issue

```
baseData.select("Open",when($"Open" <= 160, "Bad").otherwise("Good").alias("Status")).show()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
baseData.select($"Open",when($"Open" <= 160, "Bad").otherwise("Good").alias("Status")).show()
```

Comment: what was issue..? seems you added scala notation $. why can't  we add mixing both scala and sql notation?

Comment: Let me check and confirm with you

Comment: How can i rewrite the same with sql syntax?

Comment: You can't mix String and Column parameters in select

Answer (score 1):

For sql, you need to create a temp view. See below.

```
scala> val cols = Seq("Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adj_Close")
cols: Seq[String] = List(Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj_Close)

scala> val df = Seq(
     | ("2012-03-30",608.77,610.56,597.94,599.55,26050900,599.55),
     | ("2012-03-29",612.78,616.56,607.23,609.86,21668300,609.86),
     | ("2012-03-28",618.38,621.45,610.31,617.62,23385200,617.62),
     | ("2012-03-27",606.18,616.28,606.06,614.48,21628200,614.48),
     | ("2012-03-26",599.79,607.15,595.26,606.98,21259900,606.98),
     | ("2012-03-23",600.49,601.80,594.40,596.05,15359900,596.05),
     | ("2012-03-22",597.78,604.50,595.53,599.34,22281100,599.34),
     | ("2012-03-21",602.74,609.65,601.41,602.50,22958200,602.50)).toDF(cols:_*)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Date: string, Open: double ... 5 more fields]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("stocks")

scala> spark.sql(" select Open, case when Open <= 600 then 'Bad' else 'good' end status from stocks").show()
+------+------+
|  Open|status|
+------+------+
|608.77|  good|
|612.78|  good|
|618.38|  good|
|606.18|  good|
|599.79|   Bad|
|600.49|  good|
|597.78|   Bad|
|602.74|  good|
+------+------+


scala> df.select($"Open",when('open <= 600, "Bad").otherwise("good").alias("status")).show()
+------+------+
|  Open|status|
+------+------+
|608.77|  good|
|612.78|  good|
|618.38|  good|
|606.18|  good|
|599.79|   Bad|
|600.49|  good|
|597.78|   Bad|
|602.74|  good|
+------+------+


scala>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir..you are impressed. since i am a beginner. which one is prefer interms of performance

Comment: both methods will have the same execution plan, so it is of your choice.. please consider upvoting the answer